# popup of QTableView doesn't show well

Tags: qt, qtableview

I have a QTableView which show the content in popup when the mouse hover on it. In most cases it works well, but sometimes when I move the mouse, the popup become transparency. I have go through the code but still don't find out the reason.
The correct case and incorrect case are shown below.

[image]

[image]

The code related to this popup is shown below:

```
bool eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event){
    if(viewport() == watched){
        if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseMove){
            QMouseEvent *mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
            QModelIndex index = indexAt(mouseEvent->pos());
            if(index.isValid()){
                showPopup(index);
            }
            else{
                popup->hide();
            }
        }
        else if(event->type() == QEvent::Leave){
            popup->hide();
        }
    }
    else if(popup == watched){
        if(event->type() == QEvent::Leave){
            popup->hide();
        }
    }
    return QTableView::eventFilter(watched, event);d
}


void showPopup (const QModelIndex &index) const {
    if(index.column() == 1){
        QRect r = visualRect(index);
        popup->move(viewport()->mapToGlobal(r.bottomLeft()));

        QString showString = index.data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
        for (int i = 0; i<8; i++){
            showString = showString.replace(17+18*i,1,QChar(' '));
        }

        popupLabel->setText(showString);

        popup->adjustSize();
        popup->show();
    }
    else {
        popup->hide();
    }
}
```

A clue which may be useful is that when I change

```
        if(event->type() == QEvent::Leave){
            popup->hide();
        }
```

to

```
           Popup->hide();
```

The popup is always transparent. The full project is in `git@github.com:bigbigda/DbgGUI.git`

Comment: Qt isn't very good with window state modifications during mouse events. Try `QTimer::singleshot(0, popup, &QWidget::hide)`. Or try using windowflags like `Qt::Popup` for the popup, Qt can handle the closing on mouse leave on its own.

Comment: The popup has been constructed with `popup = new QDialog(this, Qt::Popup | Qt::ToolTip)`. I don't know the QTimer method, could you give a further explanation.

Comment: It deleys the execution of hide() until the event loop executed the next time.

Comment: But I wish the popup to show when my mouse move on a new item and show the new content. How can I add this timer to the popup ?

Comment: Based on yout comment, I add a `sleep 10 ms` after the `popup->show()`, it seems that the popup shows well. Although I think this is a ungly method, at least it works.

Comment: I think, from the context, you want to show the content in tooltip, you can implement this in data() Tooltip role. avoid eventFilter() altogether.

Comment: Ok, I'll give a try